# Altium trace width rule applied to blanket only

Tags: pcb-design, altium, routing

In Altium, I set a rule for PCB trace width and clearances for a high current net but I only want it applied to that blanket that I have created in the schematic.

I have monitoring lines that wont be high current but they are huge traces too can I apply the rule just to the net lines in that class/room?

e.g. apply rule to all classes in blanket ***excluding*** GND

Comment: WHat do you mean by "blanket". Are you thinking of a "polygon" or a "plane layer" or a "layer" or something else?

Comment: You can have a rule that applies only to a particular net class, or only to a particular layer, or only to a particular net. And probably you can make a class that applies only within a particular room, but I never use rooms so I can't be sure.

Comment: @JYelton - You accidentally converted the leading "in" from the statement "in altium" to "I altium".

Answer (score 2):

If you place a "parameter set" directive upon the net(s) which you want to have different rules from the blanket directive, the parameter set directive(s) should override the blanket directive.

That doesn't exclude it per se from the blanket, but it may give you what I think you want- different rules from the blanket rules, from the schematic sheet.